Construction Permit Web App
I have a Next.js + Node.js + TypeScript + Tailwind + tRPC project whose objective is to allow a construction manager to figure out what permits are required for his renovation based on if it's an exterior or interior construction project.
This is my main route ('/'):
     'use client';
    import { useState } from "react";
    import Header from "../components/Header";
    import Interior from "../components/Interior";
    import Exterior from "../components/Exterior";
    import { InteriorCheckBoxes, ExteriorCheckBoxes } from '@/types'
    import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
    import { trpc } from '@/app/_trpc/client'
    
    export default function Home() {
      // hook to allow communication with tRPC
      const createNewPermit = trpc.createNewPermitProcess.useMutation()
    
      // State to keep track of the selected option
      const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState<string>('');
    
      // State to keep track of next steps relative to result
      const nextSteps = new Map();
      nextSteps.set('inHouseReviewProcess', ['Obtain a building permit', 'Include plan sets', 'Submit application for in-house review'])
      nextSteps.set('otcSubmissionProcess', ['Obtain a building permit', 'Submit application for OTC review'])
      nextSteps.set('noPermit', [])
    
      // Initalize the router
      const router = useRouter()
    
      // State to keep track of the checked state of each external checkbox
      const [exteriorCheckboxes, setExteriorCheckboxes] = useState<ExteriorCheckBoxes>({
        garageDoorReplacement: false,
        exteriorDoors: false,
        fencing: false,
        other: false
      });
    
      // State to keep track of the checked state of each internal checkbox
      const [interiorCheckboxes, setInteriorCheckboxes] = useState<InteriorCheckBoxes>({
        bathroomRemodel: false,
        newBathroom: false,
        newLaundryRoom: false,
        other: false
      });
    
      // Validate an option was selected
      const validateOptionSelected = (): Boolean => {
    
        // One of the exterior checkboxes was selected
        if (exteriorCheckboxes.garageDoorReplacement ||
          exteriorCheckboxes.exteriorDoors ||
          exteriorCheckboxes.fencing ||
          exteriorCheckboxes.other
        ) {
          return true
        }
    
        // One of the internal checkboxes was selected
        else if (interiorCheckboxes.bathroomRemodel ||
          interiorCheckboxes.newBathroom ||
          interiorCheckboxes.newLaundryRoom ||
          interiorCheckboxes.other
        ) {
          return true
        }
    
        // nothing was selected
        else {
          return false
        }
      }
    
      // Reset checkboxes
      const resetCheckboxes = (): void => {
    
        // Reset external checkboxes
        exteriorCheckboxes.exteriorDoors = false
        exteriorCheckboxes.fencing = false
        exteriorCheckboxes.garageDoorReplacement = false
        exteriorCheckboxes.other = false
    
        // Reset internal checkboxes
        interiorCheckboxes.bathroomRemodel = false
        interiorCheckboxes.newBathroom = false
        interiorCheckboxes.newLaundryRoom = false
        interiorCheckboxes.other = false
      }
    
      // Handler function to update the selected option
      const handleSelectChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>): void => {
        setSelectedOption(event.target.value);
        resetCheckboxes()
      };
    
      // function to handle the onSubmit action
      const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault()
    
        let resultString = ""
    
        // exterior logic
        if (selectedOption === "exterior") {
          if (exteriorCheckboxes.other) {
            resultString = "inHouseReviewProcess"
          }
          else if (exteriorCheckboxes.garageDoorReplacement || exteriorCheckboxes.exteriorDoors) {
            resultString = "otcSubmissionProcess"
          }
          else {
            resultString = "noPermit"
          }
        }
        // interior logic
        else {
          if (interiorCheckboxes.bathroomRemodel) {
            resultString = "otcSubmissionProcess"
          }
          else {
            resultString = "inHouseReviewProcess"
          }
    
        }
    
        // tRPC call to persist results to the database
        const res = await createNewPermit.mutateAsync({
          process: resultString,
          nextSteps: nextSteps.get(resultString)
        });
        console.log(res)
    
        // navigate user to the results page
        router.push('/results?nextSteps=' + resultString)
      }
    
      return (
        <main>
          <Header />
          <div className="flex justify-center w-full">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="w-full max-w-lg">
              <h2 className="p-4 text-3xl font-bold">What Residential Work Are You Doing?</h2>
              <select className="select select-bordered select-lg max-w-xs mx-auto self-center ml-24" value={selectedOption} onChange={handleSelectChange}>
                <option selected>Select Renovation</option>
                <option value="interior">Interior</option>
                <option value="exterior">Exterior</option>
              </select>
              {selectedOption === "interior" && <Interior checkboxes={interiorCheckboxes} setCheckBoxes={setInteriorCheckboxes} />}
              {selectedOption === "exterior" && <Exterior checkboxes={exteriorCheckboxes} setCheckBoxes={setExteriorCheckboxes} />}
              <div className="flex justify-center">
                {selectedOption && validateOptionSelected() && <button className="btn btn-xs sm:btn-sm md:btn-md lg:btn-lg bg-blue-500 text-white m-4" type="submit">Submit</button>}
              </div>
            </form>
          </div >
        </main >
      )
    }

I also have a Results route at '/results?nextSteps={resultoptions}'
'use client';
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'

const Results = () => {
    const searchParams = useSearchParams()
    const nextSteps = searchParams.get('nextSteps')
    console.log(nextSteps)
    return (
        <div>
            {nextSteps === "inHouseReviewProcess" &&
                <div>
                    <h1 className="w-full text-center text-4xl font-bold">✅ In-House Review Process</h1>
                    <ul className="steps p-5">
                        <li className="step step-primary">Obtain a building permit</li>
                        <li className="step">Include plan sets</li>
                        <li className="step">Submit application for in-house review</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            }
            {nextSteps === "otcSubmissionProcess" &&
                <div>
                    <h1 className="w-full text-center text-4xl font-bold">✅ Over-the-Counter Submission Process</h1>
                    <ul className="steps p-5 justify-center w-full">
                        <li className="step step-primary">Obtain a building permit</li>
                        <li className="step">Submit application for OTC review</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            }
            {nextSteps === "noPermit" &&
                <div>
                    <h1 className="w-full text-center text-4xl font-bold">❌ No Permit</h1>
                    <p className="text-center py-5">{"Nothing is required! You're set to build."}</p>

                </div>
            }

        </div>
    )
}

export default Results

This is my tRPC route:
import { publicProcedure, router } from "./trpc";
import { z } from 'zod'
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

export const appRouter = router({
    createNewPermitProcess: publicProcedure
        .input(z.object({
            process: z.string(),
            nextSteps: z.array(z.string())
        }))
        // Define the output schema for the mutation (optional)
        .output(z.boolean()) // Specify that the output will be a boolean value
        .mutation(async req => {
            const { process, nextSteps } = req.input
            // Perform some mutation logic (in this case, create a new entry in the database)
            try {
                // Assuming some database operation
                const result = await prisma.permitResult.create({
                    data: {
                        processNeeded: process,
                        steps: nextSteps
                    }
                });
                // Return true if the operation was successful
                console.log(result)
                return true;
            } catch (error) {
                // If an error occurs during the operation, return false
                console.error("Error creating permit result:", error);
                return false;
            }

        })
});

export type AppRouter = typeof appRouter;

This is my prisma.schema:
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model PermitResult {
  permitId      Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  processNeeded String
  createdAt     DateTime @default(now())
  steps         String[]

  @@index([createdAt])
}

This is my Interior component:
'use client';
import React from 'react'
import { InteriorCheckBoxProps } from '@/types'

const Interior = ({ checkboxes, setCheckBoxes }: InteriorCheckBoxProps) => {
    // Handler function to toggle the checked state of a checkbox
    const handleCheckboxChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
        const { name, checked } = event.target;
        setCheckBoxes({
            ...checkboxes,
            [name]: checked
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h3 className='p-5 text-center text-2xl font-bold'>What Interior Work Are You Doing?</h3>
            <div className="grid grid-cols-2">
                {/* Checkbox input elements */}
                <label>
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        name="bathroomRemodel"
                        className="checkbox checkbox-md mx-2 border-blue-500 checked:border-blue-500 [--chkbg:theme(colors.blue.500)] [--chkfg:white]"
                        checked={checkboxes.bathroomRemodel}
                        onChange={handleCheckboxChange}
                    />
                    Bathroom Remodel
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        name="newBathroom"
                        className="checkbox checkbox-md mx-2 border-blue-500 checked:border-blue-500 [--chkbg:theme(colors.blue.500)] [--chkfg:white]"
                        checked={checkboxes.newBathroom}
                        onChange={handleCheckboxChange}
                    />
                    New Bathroom
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        name="newLaundryRoom"
                        className="checkbox checkbox-md mx-2 border-blue-500 checked:border-blue-500 [--chkbg:theme(colors.blue.500)] [--chkfg:white]"
                        checked={checkboxes.newLaundryRoom}
                        onChange={handleCheckboxChange}
                    />
                    New Laundry Room
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        name="other"
                        className="checkbox checkbox-md mx-2 border-blue-500 checked:border-blue-500 [--chkbg:theme(colors.blue.500)] [--chkfg:white]"
                        checked={checkboxes.other}
                        onChange={handleCheckboxChange}
                    />
                    Other
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Interior

This is my Exterior component:
'use client';
import React from 'react';
import { ExteriorCheckBoxProps } from '@/types'

const Exterior = ({ checkboxes, setCheckBoxes }: ExteriorCheckBoxProps) => {
    // Handler function to toggle the checked state of a checkbox
    const handleCheckboxChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
        const { name, checked } = event.target;
        setCheckBoxes({
            ...checkboxes,
            [name]: checked
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h3 className='p-5 text-center text-2xl font-bold'>What Exterior Work Are You Doing?</h3>
            <div className="grid grid-cols-2">
                {/* Checkbox input elements */}
                <label>
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        name="garageDoorReplacement"
                        className="checkbox checkbox-md mx-2 border-blue-500 checked:border-blue-500 [--chkbg:theme(colors.blue.500)] [--chkfg:white]"
                        checked={checkboxes.garageDoorReplacement}
                        onChange={handleCheckboxChange}
                    />
                    Garage Door Replacement
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        name="exteriorDoors"
                        className="checkbox checkbox-md mx-2 border-blue-500 checked:border-blue-500 [--chkbg:theme(colors.blue.500)] [--chkfg:white]"
                        checked={checkboxes.exteriorDoors}
                        onChange={handleCheckboxChange}
                    />
                    Exterior Doors
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        name="fencing"
                        className="checkbox checkbox-md mx-2 border-blue-500 checked:border-blue-500 [--chkbg:theme(colors.blue.500)] [--chkfg:white]"
                        checked={checkboxes.fencing}
                        onChange={handleCheckboxChange}
                    />
                    Fencing
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        name="other"
                        className="checkbox checkbox-md mx-2 border-blue-500 checked:border-blue-500 [--chkbg:theme(colors.blue.500)] [--chkfg:white]"
                        checked={checkboxes.other}
                        onChange={handleCheckboxChange}
                    />
                    Other
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Exterior

Inside of my "tests" directory, I have created 2 test files for testing the Interior.tsx and Exterior.tsx components
Interior.test.tsx
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
const { expect, describe, it } = require('@jest/globals');
import { Interior } from '@/components';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { InteriorCheckBoxes } from '@/types';

describe('Interior component', () => {
    it('Contains Title What Interior Work Are You Doing?', () => {
        const InteriorWrapper = () => {
            // State to keep track of the checked state of each internal checkbox
            const [interiorCheckboxes, setInteriorCheckboxes] = useState<InteriorCheckBoxes>({
                bathroomRemodel: false,
                newBathroom: false,
                newLaundryRoom: false,
                other: false
            });

            return <Interior checkboxes={interiorCheckboxes} setCheckBoxes={setInteriorCheckboxes} />;
        };

        render(<InteriorWrapper />);
        const myElem = screen.getByText('What Interior Work Are You Doing?');
        expect(myElem).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    it('Contains checkbox Bathroom Remodel', () => {
        const InteriorWrapper = () => {
            // State to keep track of the checked state of each internal checkbox
            const [interiorCheckboxes, setInteriorCheckboxes] = useState<InteriorCheckBoxes>({
                bathroomRemodel: false,
                newBathroom: false,
                newLaundryRoom: false,
                other: false
            });

            return <Interior checkboxes={interiorCheckboxes} setCheckBoxes={setInteriorCheckboxes} />;
        };

        render(<InteriorWrapper />);
        const myElem = screen.getByText('Bathroom Remodel')
        expect(myElem).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    it('Contains checkbox New Bathroom', () => {
        const InteriorWrapper = () => {
            // State to keep track of the checked state of each internal checkbox
            const [interiorCheckboxes, setInteriorCheckboxes] = useState<InteriorCheckBoxes>({
                bathroomRemodel: false,
                newBathroom: false,
                newLaundryRoom: false,
                other: false
            });

            return <Interior checkboxes={interiorCheckboxes} setCheckBoxes={setInteriorCheckboxes} />;
        };

        render(<InteriorWrapper />);
        const myElem = screen.getByText('New Bathroom')
        expect(myElem).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    it('Contains checkbox New Laundry Room', () => {
        const InteriorWrapper = () => {
            // State to keep track of the checked state of each internal checkbox
            const [interiorCheckboxes, setInteriorCheckboxes] = useState<InteriorCheckBoxes>({
                bathroomRemodel: false,
                newBathroom: false,
                newLaundryRoom: false,
                other: false
            });

            return <Interior checkboxes={interiorCheckboxes} setCheckBoxes={setInteriorCheckboxes} />;
        };

        render(<InteriorWrapper />);
        const myElem = screen.getByText('New Laundry Room')
        expect(myElem).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    it('Contains checkbox Other', () => {
        const InteriorWrapper = () => {
            // State to keep track of the checked state of each internal checkbox
            const [interiorCheckboxes, setInteriorCheckboxes] = useState<InteriorCheckBoxes>({
                bathroomRemodel: false,
                newBathroom: false,
                newLaundryRoom: false,
                other: false
            });

            return <Interior checkboxes={interiorCheckboxes} setCheckBoxes={setInteriorCheckboxes} />;
        };

        render(<InteriorWrapper />);
        const myElem = screen.getByText('Other')
        expect(myElem).toBeInTheDocument();
    });


});

Exterior.test.tsx:
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
const { expect, describe, it } = require('@jest/globals');
import { Exterior } from '@/components';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { ExteriorCheckBoxes } from '@/types';

describe('Exterior component', () => {
    it('Contains Title What Exterior Work Are You Doing?', () => {
        const ExteriorWrapper = () => {
            const [exteriorCheckboxes, setExteriorCheckboxes] = useState<ExteriorCheckBoxes>({
                garageDoorReplacement: false,
                exteriorDoors: false,
                fencing: false,
                other: false
            });

            return <Exterior checkboxes={exteriorCheckboxes} setCheckBoxes={setExteriorCheckboxes} />;
        };

        render(<ExteriorWrapper />);
        const myElem = screen.getByText('What Exterior Work Are You Doing?');
        expect(myElem).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    it('Contains checkbox Garage Door Replacement', () => {
        const ExteriorWrapper = () => {
            const [exteriorCheckboxes, setExteriorCheckboxes] = useState<ExteriorCheckBoxes>({
                garageDoorReplacement: false,
                exteriorDoors: false,
                fencing: false,
                other: false
            });

            return <Exterior checkboxes={exteriorCheckboxes} setCheckBoxes={setExteriorCheckboxes} />;
        };

        render(<ExteriorWrapper />);
        const myElem = screen.getByText('Garage Door Replacement')
        expect(myElem).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    it('Contains checkbox Exterior Doors', () => {
        const ExteriorWrapper = () => {
            const [exteriorCheckboxes, setExteriorCheckboxes] = useState<ExteriorCheckBoxes>({
                garageDoorReplacement: false,
                exteriorDoors: false,
                fencing: false,
                other: false
            });

            return <Exterior checkboxes={exteriorCheckboxes} setCheckBoxes={setExteriorCheckboxes} />;
        };

        render(<ExteriorWrapper />);
        const myElem = screen.getByText('Exterior Doors')
        expect(myElem).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    it('Contains checkbox Fencing', () => {
        const ExteriorWrapper = () => {
            const [exteriorCheckboxes, setExteriorCheckboxes] = useState<ExteriorCheckBoxes>({
                garageDoorReplacement: false,
                exteriorDoors: false,
                fencing: false,
                other: false
            });

            return <Exterior checkboxes={exteriorCheckboxes} setCheckBoxes={setExteriorCheckboxes} />;
        };

        render(<ExteriorWrapper />);
        const myElem = screen.getByText('Fencing')
        expect(myElem).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    it('Contains checkbox Other', () => {
        const ExteriorWrapper = () => {
            const [exteriorCheckboxes, setExteriorCheckboxes] = useState<ExteriorCheckBoxes>({
                garageDoorReplacement: false,
                exteriorDoors: false,
                fencing: false,
                other: false
            });

            return <Exterior checkboxes={exteriorCheckboxes} setCheckBoxes={setExteriorCheckboxes} />;
        };

        render(<ExteriorWrapper />);
        const myElem = screen.getByText('Other')
        expect(myElem).toBeInTheDocument();
    });


});

I'd love to hear thoughts on anything you feel could be improved - code quality, best practices, performance, etc.

Please feel free to add your automated unit tests to this submission. It seems likely the business logic will change in coming months, as the business expands and the regulatory environment changes.

I've updated the submission to showcase both my tests inside my test directory. Still working on making tests for my Home and Results component

I don't have time for a review, but passing state hooks into props of a component seems like an antipattern. State should be controlled internally, only accessible through prescribed wrapper functions with a clear API that control exactly how the state is mutated. RTL was created to avoid testing implementation details, like how the state is managed (hooks vs context vs class component vs whatever). The Home component is overburdened managing state that should be managed by its children, who aren't properly offloading the burden on Home.

I'd also suggest running your code through prettier and eslint.
